# How to build a single CPP file for test?

Tags: platformio

I want to create a test for a `.cpp` file in my Arduino project using PlatformIO. This is my `platformio.ini`:

```
[env:mkrwifi1010]
platform = atmelsam
board = mkrwifi1010
framework = arduino
lib_deps = 
    arduino-libraries/LiquidCrystal@^1.0.7
    ivanseidel/LinkedList@0.0.0-alpha+sha.dac3874d28
    arduino-libraries/WiFiNINA@^1.8.13
    bblanchon/ArduinoJson@^6.21.1

[env:native_test]
platform = native
build_src_filter = +<nmea.cpp>
```

But this gives me this error:

```
g++ -o .pio/build/native_test/program .pio/build/native_test/src/nmea.o -L.pio/build/native_test
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/12/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x1b): undefined reference to `main'
```

I only build my `nmea.cpp` file, that has one `Nmea` class inside. Obviously I do not have a `main`, as my test code has the `main`.

How can I build to native for test just for a single cpp file?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add `test_build_src` to my `[env]`, like this is works fine:

```
[env:native_test]
platform = native
test_build_src = yes
build_src_filter = +<nmea.cpp>
```

This runs the test on the native platform (i.e. my laptop), and only builds `nmea.cpp` and the test code (which has the `main` defined). The `native_test` won't build (because missing `main`), but it does run all tests.